# How to use loadasync method of PictureBox thereby accepting a resource image as a parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to use loadasync method of PictureBox while making image changed in windows form application. If I give path of image as a parameter such as "../../Image/ok32.png" in this method , it causes an error when I run exe outside of the project. Because of that, I know that I must use images in resources of properties.

However, I do not know how I can do.

```
namespace MyFirstApp
{
    public partial class MqttManager : Form
    {
        MqttHandler mqttHandler = new MqttHandler();
        public static MqttManager managerInst;

        public MqttManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            managerInst = this;
            ...
            String[] a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
            statusPctBox.LoadAsync(@".\Images\x32.png");
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When I use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(), I get a string[] such as;

[image]

Actually, I have three image files in resource part of properties file in my project, I can see in Visual Studio.

How to use loadasync method of PictureBox thereby accepting a resource image as a parameter?

**EDIT:**
I've changed build action of one of an image then I get this result below;

[image]

However, "statusPctBox.LoadAsync(@a[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cWh2.png));" still does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to do that whatsoever.

`LoadAsync` is used to load a picture when some I/O is involved. In the case of a resource image, the image is already loaded in memory, and there's no (visible) asynchronous I/O involved.

Just use `statusPctBox.Image = Resources.Images.x32;` or something like that.

Note that your debugger output shows that your image is *not* a resource after all - you need to change the build action to Embedded Resource.

Comment: I edit the question after your recommendation. May u look at it?

Comment: @sean35 Just stop using `LoadAsync` - it's used to load *files* and URLs, not resources.